# how to kill my code running in background without task manager?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

hi I have recently started c++ on vs-code,

first I wrote a program for sum of two no. then edited it to difference of two no. it was still showing the previous output ,I figured out that the program was running in background so I ended
it in task manager.

my question is -

will I always have to use task manager to kill my program running in background or is there a more efficient way in vs-code.

previous code-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a;
cin>>a;
int b;
cin>>b;
int c;
cin>>c;
int s=(c+a+b)/3;
cout<<s;
return 0;
}
```

edited code-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a;
cin>>a;
int b;
cin>>b;
int c;
cin>>c;
int s=(c+a+b)/6;
cout<<s;
return 0;
}
```

I save the code in the end and re-run it but it shows the previous output.
thanks

Comment: I have tried terminating the program in vs code but it didn't work, it still showed the previous output.so I used task manager.

Comment: There must be a button to build AND run, instead of just running the program. You need to recompile your program.

Comment: For a program that takes two inputs, adds or subtracts them, print the result, it should exit once that is done. If it doesn't then your program have a bug. Or you're not running it normally. So please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the code, and tell us exactly how you build and run the programs.

Comment: The programs created from the shown code should have exited once they are finished. So the problem isn't with the code itself, but something else. ***How do you run your programs?***

Comment: Also, what is your input to the programs? Is it the *same* input for both programs? And remember you're doing *integer* arithmetic with integer results. So `(1 + 1 + 1) / 3` will be equal to `1`, but `(1 + 1 + 1) / 6` will be equal to `0`. Also `(2 + 2 + 2) / 6` will also be equal to `1`.